# How to fill columns in R based on matching parts of one column to values in another data frame

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one with my data (`data`) and one with a lookup table (`lookup`). The data includes a column called `claims`; its cells are filled with one or more codes identifying the types of legal claims brought in a particular case (each row represents one case). Multiple types of claims are separated by a semicolon.

The `lookup` data frame has three columns: `code`, `category`, and `so_category`. The `code` column lists each unique claim code used in the `claims` column of `data`. `category` contains a category I assigned to that kind of claim, and `so_category` assigns a higher-level category into which that particular `category` fits.

What I'm trying to do is add columns to `data` for each `category` and `so_category` that will just be filled with 0 or 1 depending on whether there are `claims` in the case that correspond to each `category` and `so_category`.

Below is an example of what my data frames look like:

```
data
Case      claims
1         wiretap;fdcpa
2         ca_ucl;comlaw
3         tort;comlaw;wiretap;ca_ucl
```

```
lookup
code     category     so_category
wiretap  f_wiretap    f_statute
fdcpa    f_con_prot   f_statute
ca_ucl   st_con_prot  st_statute
comlaw   com_law      common_law
tort     com_law      common_law
```

So what I would like to generate programmatically is something like:

```
data
Case      claims                      f_stat   st_stat   common_law
1         wiretap;fdcpa               1        0         0
2         ca_ucl;comlaw               0        1         1
3         tort;comlaw;wiretap;ca_ucl  1        1         1
```

I'm quite new to R and am pretty much at a loss to figure out how to do this--any guidance would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, we can find all the `unique` `so_category` (`all_category`) with which we need to match. Split the `claims` on `;` and `match` each one of them with the `code` in `lookup` and get the corresponding `so_category` and give 1/0 values based on presence/absence of the category in `all_category`.

```
all_category <- unique(lookup$so_category)

data[all_category] <- t(sapply(strsplit(data$claims, ";"), function(x)
          as.integer(all_category %in% lookup$so_category[match(x, lookup$code)])))

data
#  Case                     claims f_statute st_statute common_law
#1    1              wiretap;fdcpa         1          0          1
#2    2              ca_ucl;comlaw         0          1          1
#3    3 tort;comlaw;wiretap;ca_ucl         1          1          1
```

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(Case = 1:3, claims = c("wiretap;fdcpa", 
"ca_ucl;comlaw", "tort;comlaw;wiretap;ca_ucl")), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

lookup <- structure(list(code = c("wiretap", "fdcpa", "ca_ucl", "comlaw", 
"tort"), category = c("f_wiretap", "f_con_prot", "st_con_prot", 
"com_law", "com_law"), so_category = c("f_statute", "f_statute", 
"st_statute", "common_law", "common_law")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! When I try running what you've suggested on the full `data` set, it throws an error: "replacement element 1 has 5 rows, need 182". `data` does indeed have 182 rows, and the full `so_category` has 5.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option with `tidyverse`, where we split the 'claims' column at the delimiter `;` with `separate_rows`, then do a join (`left_join`) with the 'lookup' dataset, `spread` it to 'wide' format after getting the `distinct` rows and join the output with the original dataset

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
  separate_rows(claims, sep=";") %>%
  left_join(lookup, by = c("claims" = "code")) %>%
  select(-claims, -category) %>%
  distinct(Case, so_category) %>% 
  mutate(val = 1) %>% 
  spread(so_category, val, fill = 0) %>% 
  right_join(data) %>% 
  select(names(data), everything())
#   Case                     claims common_law f_statute st_statute
#1    1              wiretap;fdcpa          0         1          0
#2    2              ca_ucl;comlaw          1         0          1
#3    3 tort;comlaw;wiretap;ca_ucl          1         1          1
```

#### data

```
data <- structure(list(Case = 1:3, claims = c("wiretap;fdcpa", 
"ca_ucl;comlaw", "tort;comlaw;wiretap;ca_ucl")), 
row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

lookup <- structure(list(code = c("wiretap", "fdcpa", "ca_ucl", "comlaw", 
"tort"), category = c("f_wiretap", "f_con_prot", "st_con_prot", 
"com_law", "com_law"), so_category = c("f_statute", "f_statute", 
"st_statute", "common_law", "common_law")), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```